# Why does switch cause cannot resolve error?

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, osgi, switch-statement

I have an enum in package A which has a static converter method, which I use to get the appropriate enum type for a particular set of classes in another package B (each class in the other package has a corresponding enum).

Now, from a third package C, which does not import package A, but does import package B I'm trying to switch on the enum.

Now, when I use a `switch` to check the enum, it complains:

> The type nz.ac.waikato.jstar.jStar.OrderOperator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class 
>    files

However, when I use an if statement it doesn't.

Can anyone shed light as to why the `switch` causes the error but the `if` doesn't?

Code:

```
//Doesn't work
switch (connection.getType()) {
    case LESS_THAN:
        break;
    case LESS_THAN_EQUALS:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

//Works Fine
if(connection.getType() == OrderingConnectionType.LESS_THAN) {
    return -1;
} else if(connection.getType() == OrderingConnectionType.LESS_THAN_EQUALS) {
    return 2;
}
```

Enum's static method that refers to bundle A (OrderOperator is from Bundle A):

```
public static OrderingConnectionType getType(Class<? extends OrderOperator> operatorType) {
    for (OrderingConnectionType type : OrderingConnectionType.values()) {
        if(type.operatorType.isAssignableFrom(operatorType)) return type;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Operator type: " + operatorType);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

Add OrderingConnectionType. prefix to cases of the switch, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

you should give exact enum type to compare.. you are doing this in `if statement` but not in `switch`.

```
switch (connection.getType()) {
    case OrderingConnectionType.LESS_THAN:
        break;
    case OrderingConnectionType.LESS_THAN_EQUALS:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Actually, when I tried this it gave a different error: 
"The qualified case label OrderingConnectionType.LESS_THAN must be replaced with the unqualified enum constant LESS_THAN"

Answer (score 0):

Check your import statement. The LESS_THAN and LESS_THAN_EQUALS enum values are probably being imported from the type `nz.ac.waikato.jstar.jStar.OrderOperator` rather than your own `OrderingConnectionType`.

Comment: No, OrderOperator is a superclass with two subclasses - OrderLessThan and OrderLessThanEqual.